# Flex iOS application with rtmps

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, endpoint, rtmps

I am trying to connect to an rtmps endpoint in AIR.

The code looks like this:

```
private function onCreationComplete():void{
    var conn:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    conn.connect("rtmps://someserver.com/someapplication"); 
    conn.proxyType = "best";
    conn.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,statusHandler);
}

private function statusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
    var conn:NetConnection = NetConnection(event.target);
    trace(event.info.code);
}
```

This actually works perfectly when running the app on the desktop in ADL (emulator).
However when I install the application (.ipa) on the iPad, the connection fails.

Both my desktop and the iPad connect to the same wireless network (thus use the same network architecture to connect)

Has anyone experienced this kind of behaviour before?

Cheers

Comment: I can only offer cursory help. I've heard of folks who have had things work in emulator, but not on device. I know iOS blocks certain behaviors.  I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is one of them.  I wonder if the iOS Emulator does not properly 'limit' functionality.  Good luck!

Comment: My first hunch would be that there might be some certificate issue since I guess that it will be handled by the OS itself through an API in the AIR runtime.
I would like to find a spec on this :)

Comment: And indeed, there are some issues with the emulator since people are logging feature requests in the adobe jira 
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-31245

Comment: It appears that my first hunch was the right one.

I noticed that our streaming server has an AES 256 bit certificate, which is apparently not supported in iOS by default.

Comment: @DennisJaamann, When you find the fix, please post it as this might be helpful for other people. Also, the hell is apple thinking with no 256 AES support?

Comment: Well, at this moment I'm not sure yet whether they don't support it.
However when browsing to the our server root url, it loads in every browser on every operating system except for iOS (with AES 256).
When doing the same with an AES 128 server like encrypted.google.com it tends to be working in safari in iOS as well. This implies that it looks like some SSL handshake is failing. Trying to determine now whether its the server setup or the certificate.

Comment: @J_A_X, we have ruled out the certificate as the culprit, read my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a problem with Air 3.1.
I have raised a bug report with Adobe - https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3133542

Comment: You can get rtmps connections on iOS to work with Flex, but you have to use a recognised SSL certificate, not a self-generated one. When connecting using a self cert with Android you get the option to authorise it, where as iOS just silently fails. So buy a cert from someone like Verisign and you should be good. My companies app myCast (http://codeghost.co.uk/mycast) is built with Flex and can successfully connect to rtmps.

Answer (score 1):

After some serious efforts to figure out what was wrong here,

We were unable to establish a connection to our server via `rtmps`.
Regular `rtmp` seems to be fine but is not unfortunately not an option for us.

****EDIT****
This problem was solved in the AIR 3.1 release.
Turns out connecting via WIFI + Proxy via RTMPS was failing for iOS.
Check out the [AIR 3.1 release notes](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/923/cpsid_92350.html) for more information on this.

Comment: Is it working reliably for you? Investigating RTMPS on iOS with AIR vs going native Obj C.

Answer (score 1):

We establish connection to the server only through the RTMP protocol.use rtmp instead rtmps,the connection can be established.